# Regex to match Character+space+character pattern

Tags: java, regex, split

In my Java program, I have a string like `G C / F C / F C / F A / B / F / I`

I am not much comfortable with Regex and would like to break the above string like below

**G**

**C / F**

**C / F**

**C / F**

**A / B / F / I**

Break it using some regex pattern like if character+space+character occurs, break the string.

---

*Added from the comments*

By character I meant [A-Z]. Tried this

```
(\s([a-zA-Z]\s)+)
```

but didn't work.

Comment: "character+space+character" would also break `A / B`, `F / I`. Please precise the requirements, and please share what you tried.

Comment: Sorry, by character I meant [A-Z]. Tried this '(\s([a-zA-Z]\s)+)' but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern can be used with [find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) to extract the desired substrings.

```
[A-Z](?:\s/\s[A-Z])*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FYpOU3/1) or a [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVDLTsMwELz7K1Y9OYg6nIkqVFBBkVqEVLjQ9GASkzo4iWVvShHqtwc3catQwR5mrVnP7KPgWz4uso@2laWuDULhCNagVMyIXOzYgmO6ESYi/9SfOKIwVURIqri1MNvxUisB3wRc6OZNyRQscnRpW8sMSi4rukQjq3y1Bm5yG/jPh3iXFVfQl6HrABMYrabj1zW9uU4SmyShw44ILkbR30LbJ6d8gDsI4f4XTh3edq8Q4oHFmZffDLTPkyPD0rrUUgnazXd5ohcv8@d4Hj/OgvOx/BHd7n2eHE2ZZ2g/8UD4uXEdgPo6cz4ZDYaXOsTyy6IoWd0g006PqjoJclM3ml4FA8s96XFP2vYH)

There is not much to explain here. Just a [repeated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `(?:` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `)` containing the slash part. If you want to match lower letters as well, simply add those to the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Slash does not need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

This regex is pretty simple and seems to work:

```js
let regex = /([A-Z])\s([A-Z])/g;
let str = 'G C / F C / F C / F A / B / F / I';
str = str.replace(regex, '$1\n$2');
console.log(str);
```